# How to run Arch Linux pacaur non-interactively?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I want to be able to install packages unattended with the Arch Linux
package manager `pacaur`. On Ubuntu, one can do:

```
apt-get -y install htop
```

What is the equivalent in Arch Linux, using Pacaur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `pacaur` [supports `--noconfirm`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacaur#Usage):

```
--noconfirm      do not prompt for any confirmation
```

The following may also be useful:

```
--noedit         do not prompt to edit files
```

Comment: I haven't been able to test this; hopefully it does what you would like it to do.

Comment: ➜  ~  pacaur -S --noconfirm google-chrome
:: Package(s) google-chrome not found in repositories, trying AUR...
:: resolving dependencies...
:: looking for inter-conflicts...

AUR Packages  (1): google-chrome-42.0.2311.90-1  

:: Retrieving package(s)...
:: View google-chrome PKGBUILD? [Y/n] 
=======================================> it did not work :(

Comment: you set me on the right path, this works:: pacaur -S --noconfirm --noedit google-chrome

Comment: Good, I will add this to my answer, then.